# JVM Thread Dump Analysis Tools for Java 7

Tags: glassfish, jvm, threadpool, analysis, dump

I create **thread dumps** for my **Glassfish 3.1.2** JVM with either **jstack** or asadmin. I try to load them into analysis tools like **samurai** (http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html), or **tda** (http://java.net/projects/tda) or **IBM** tool (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c) but all tools open the dump as textfile and do not perform any analysis.
I suspect the format changed from Java 6 to 7. Is anyone aware of a tool which can handle current thread dumps format ?

Thanks
Sven

Comment: could you post what you see e.g. in TDA? I would not expect the thread dump format to change considerably in Java7...

Comment: just an editor view, see
http://javadude.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/td.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisualVM can do the job.
Open hprof and tdump files. Still tdump files remain text only, but with hprof files some analysis can be done.